# SuperSort Matrix Block sort by Year / Month / Now Data

Tags: matrix, blocks, plugin-supersort

```
      {% set allCVs = entry.profileCv.all() %}
      {% set cvEntries = [] %}

      {% for item in allCVs %}
        {% set fromMonth = item.fromMonth.value %}
        {% set fromYear = item.fromYear %}
        {% set toMonth = item.untilToday ? now|date('n') : item.toMonth.value %}
        {% set toYear = item.untilToday ? now|date('Y') : item.toYear %}
        {% set fromMonth = fromMonth|length == 1 ? '0' ~ fromMonth : fromMonth %}
        {% set toMonth = toMonth|length == 1 ? '0' ~ toMonth : toMonth %}
        {% set cvEntries = cvEntries|merge([{
        sortKey: toYear|default(fromYear) ~ '.' ~ toMonth|default(fromMonth) ~ '-' ~ fromYear ~ '.' ~ fromMonth,
        fromMonth: fromMonth,
        fromYear: fromYear,
        toMonth: toMonth,
        toYear: item.untilToday ? now|date('Y') : item.toYear,
        type: item.experienceType,
        label: item.label,
        untilToday: item.untilToday
        }]) %}
      {% endfor %}


      {% for item in cvEntries|supersort('sortAs', '{sortKey}') %}
        {% include 'profile/_profile-cv-row' with {
        from: {
        month: item.fromMonth,
        year: item.fromYear
        },
        to: {
        month: item.toMonth,
        year: item.toYear
        },
        untilToday: item.untilToday|default(0),
        type: item.experienceType,
        label: item.label,
        description: item.description,
        trainer: item.trainer,
        certificationTitle: item.certification.one().title is defined ? item.certification.one().title : 'title',
        certificationDescription: item.certification.one().certificationDescription is defined ? item.certification.one().certificationDescription : 'description',
        } %}
      {% endfor %}
```

So what i want to do is to let supertsort sort my matrix blocks depending on the the data from

```
"sortKey: toYear|default(fromYear) ~ '.' ~ toMonth|default(fromMonth) ~ '-' ~ fromYear ~ '.' ~ fromMonth,"
```

But i get the errors:

Key "experienceType" for array with keys "sortKey, fromMonth, fromYear, toMonth, toYear, type, label, untilToday" does not exist.

Key "description" for array with keys "sortKey, fromMonth, fromYear, toMonth, toYear, type, label, untilToday" does not exist.

Key "trainer" for array with keys "sortKey, fromMonth, fromYear, toMonth, toYear, type, label, untilToday" does not exist.

If i delete all this 3 from my second loop, there is no error anymore, but of course missing data in the frontend.

Any idea whats wrong?